# CSS - Vertical spacing ignored

Tags: css

In the simple example below, I would like to understand why the vertical padding of the parent is not applied whereas the horizontal padding is applied.

**HTML**:

```
<span class="button"><a href="#">Link</a></span>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    background-color: gray;
}
span.button {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
span.button a {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**RESULT**:

[image]

**EXPECTED**:

[image]

**NOTE**:

I don't try to reproduce `border` style, this is only an example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because top/bottom padding doesn't work on inline (like `<span>` or `<a>`) elements. Fix it with this:

```
span.button, span.button a { display: inline-block }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qe5Js/